# FxCopAnalyzers: An instance of analyzer cannot be created

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, fxcop

I'm trying to install [fxcop analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/2.9.3) in my project. However, having added and restored the nuget package, building the project results in hundreds of warnings of the form

```
1>CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.AnalyzerVersionCheckAnalyzer cannot be created from 
C:\<MyProjectPath>\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.2.9.3\analyzers\dotnet\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.dll : 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified..
```

However, if I look in the path `packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionCheckAnalyzer.2.9.3\analyzers\dotnet`, I see the dll being mentioned just exists.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong? Maybe some dependency not being met. But if so, how can I tell which? I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your package path `C:\<MyProjectPath>\packages`, your project targets .net framework. Maybe you have a similar issue like [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1825).

I can reproduce same issue in one .net framework project in VS2019, and to work around this, I update the [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/3.1.1) package to latest stable version(3.1.1) and then those warnings disappear. So if you've referenced the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` pacakge, update it to latest version. If not, add reference to its latest version.

Comment: This is very plausible, because I do use an old version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers, and if I remove that dependency it works. Unfortunately I cannot afford to upgrade that package at this point.

Comment: It doesn't work, I used toolset Microsoft.Net.Compilers.toolset 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

If you have a version of [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/2.9.10) that is too high for your version of Visual Studio you can get this warning

> warning CS8032 ...

To find the max version supported see this documentation: Install FxCop analyzers in Visual Studio -> [FxCopAnalyzers package versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/install-fxcop-analyzers?view=vs-2017#fxcopanalyzers-package-versions)

Answer (score 0):

I've got rid of these errors by upgrading the following nugger

```
Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```